# Javascript making combinations with an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find all combinations and create an array of string from an array. For example:

```
var text_array = [["h"],["e","è","é","ê","ë"],["l"],["l"],["o","ò","ó","ô","õ"]]

output = ["hello","hèllo","héllo",etc...]
```

I have tried several ways but they all seemed extremely long winded and I think I'm just maybe missing a function I don't know about.

Comment: Hint: *You need a nested loop.*

Comment: show us your best shot to start with!

Comment: @LelioFaieta my best shot I'm almost certain is shameful, I basically used a for loop within a for loop x amount of times depending on how many characters there were. But this obviously only works for a certain amount of characters.

Answer (score 1):

One way to abstract the implementation from the number of characters is to incrementally build the list of final values and the values themselves. You start with an empty result, `[""]`. Then you take the first list of variants and add each variant to every result we have so far, producing a new list of intermediate results, `["h"]`.

The second list of variants has multiple elements, so after this iteration you'll have this list of results, `["he", "hè", "hé", "hê", "hë"]`. And so on.

In pseudo-code, it could look like this:

```
results = [""]

for each list_of_variants in text_array {
  new_results = []
  for each variant in list_of_variants {
    for each result in results {
      new_result.push(result + variant)
    }
  }
  results = new_results
}
```